# Will my iOS app calculate figures when a comma is used instead of a decimal point?

Tags: ios, iphone, numbers, decimal

New to iOS development and I'm just making a little wage-type calculator for a starter. I'm exploring different features, including making the app available in France and other non-English native countries.

However, as my application is heavily reliant upon calculating figures which have a decimal point in them, I want to know if iOS will calculate the figure if a comma is used as a decimal point, as countries like France use this notation:

Australia/United States/other countries:

```
12.5 * 15.8 = 197.5
```

France/other countries:

```
12,5 * 15,8 = 197,5
```

I am pretty much asking a) if a comma is inserted rather than a decimal point, will it still calculate on local devices, and b) if not, what code should I include in my application such that it will calculate this notation? (Note that I am not asking for a comma as a separator, but what acts as the equivalent of a decimal point.)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Using it as a string: YES/ Depends on the implementation. Declaring it in code: NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, iOS has a handy class built-in to handle the localization of numerical values.  It's called [NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and it specifically has the [-setDecimalSeparator:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setDecimalSeparator%3a) method.

Comment: If the docs look and feel like OSX documentation, it's because Apple hasn't gotten around to separating them yet.  Rest assured most, if not all, the detailed methods and properties are valid in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Before using the figure, you should "normalize" it by converting it to an NSNumber. Here's how:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];    
NSNumber *myNumber = [formatter numberFromString:@"197.5"];
```

This is the correct way to do it, and using this method will take into account the regional preferences, comma separators etc.

At this point, myNumber can be used as a decimal, float, integer etc.

```
float myFloat = [myNumber floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

> Will my iOS app calculate figures when a comma is used instead of a decimal point?

**Yes.** It'll do it fairly transparently as long as you use `NSNumberFormatter`.

> I want to know if iOS will calculate the figure if a comma is used as
>   a decimal point, as countries like France use this notation...

Information about how such things as numbers and dates should be formatted is managed by the `NSLocale` class. `NSNumberFormatter` uses the current locale to figure out how to interpret and display numbers, so when you use the `-numberFromString:` method, the formatter will use the appropriate decimal separator. Same thing when you generate a string representation of a number using `-stringFromNumber:`.

For your purposes you probably don't have to worry about locales. Just use a number formatter to interpret input and generate output, and the formatter will use the locale that's appropriate for the user. However, if you want your app to provide information localized to a language or region other than the user's you can use the [`-setLocale:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNumberFormatter/setLocale%3a) method to set a number formatter to use a specific locale.